# IIS6 registry values in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, windows-registry

I am  looking for the location of the IIS6 registry values such as EnableNonUTF8, FavorUTF8, MaxFieldLength, and a few more in IIS7.  In IIS6 they were in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters
```

I cannot find where to modify these in IIS7.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this article http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B820129&x=14&y=10, the settings still apply for IIS 7 (see "Applies to" section at the bottom).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I would upvote this if I could lol.